# Is there a way to determine the adjacent (previous and / or next) table rows receiving a dropped row when using jQueryUI Sortable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, tablerow

I'm using the [jQueryUI Sortable plugin](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/) on a table and everything seems to be working fine. (The HTML validates and the JavaScript all validates, too.) As far as I can tell, there is no way to determine the location of where in the table you are "dropping" a row (other than the x/y coordinates, which are useless to me).

Is it possible to do such a thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are moving whole row, after sorting is done, you have the item you dragged in all $.sortable callbacks under ui.item (not only position of it). You can then look in your $table to check how you sorted rows look like now or like in an example, get the index of row straight.

```
$('table').sortable({
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    console.log(ui.item.index());
    console.log(ui.item.next());
    console.log(ui.item.prev());
  }
})
```

Bonus: working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rFWUP/) (original by shuklendu, i just forked and adjusted)

Comment: Thanks! It's a bit different with a TABLE instead of a list, but I got it working just the same.